# UITapGestureRecognizer not working at all

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have been tasked to add an audio player into a pre-existing iPad/iPhone app.  I have been struggling for the past two days trying to figure out why I cannot get a simple tap gesture to work. I have scoured the internet to no avail. I know there are several questions that already exist like this, but I am still very stuck.  Please help!  The area I am working in is inside a tableview with cells.  I am adding a subiew into some of the cells which start from as a view called "background" and other views are added to it.  I have added a simple UIView containing a play button.  My "play button" view is constructed from a method like so:

```
-(UIView*) messagePlayerImageViewForMessage:(LAZMessage*) message {
UIView* returnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
UIImageView* playButtonImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[returnView addSubview:playButtonImageView];
playButtonImageView.tag = TAG_CELL_PLAY_IMAGE_VIEW;

if ([self stringForMessageRecordingId:message]) {
    UIImage* playButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"play"];
    [playButtonImageView setImage:playButton];
    [playButtonImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, playButton.size.width/2, playButton.size.height/2)];

    [returnView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, playButtonImageView.frame.size.width, playButtonImageView.frame.size.height)];
}
returnView.tag = TAG_CELL_MESSAGE_PLAYER_VIEW;
return returnView;
}
```

After creating this subview I append it to the cell view and try to add GestureRecognizers like so

```
UIView* messagePlayerView = [self messagePlayerImageViewForMessage:message];
messagePlayerView.tag = TAG_CELL_MESSAGE_PLAYER_VIEW;
messagePlayerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[background addSubview:messagePlayerView];

UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[messagePlayerView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
tapGesture.delegate = self;
```

The corresponding tap function is

```
-(void) handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*) tapGestureRecognizer{
    NSLog(@"hi");
}
```

Inside ViewController.h, the class is declared as  and I have added the following code inside the ViewController.m file

```
-(BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

There is no .xib, this all done programatically.

Any ideas?  Any thoughts on how I could begin to debug this?

EDIT:

I added the UITapGestureRecognizer to the UITableView and this will register a tap.  Does anybody have any ideas how to get that tap to trickle down to the particular subview I want.

Comment: Is this a typo? UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc];
initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];

Comment: Yes, there is no extra semi-colon, sorry.  The line in my code appears like so:     UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];

Comment: Hey, what sort of view is "background"? A UIImageView or a UIView?

Comment: Declared like so, UIView* background;  And this is declared inside of - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath.  That function adds a couple other subviews to background, then background is added to the cell, which is of UITableViewCell* .

Comment: I recommend you make a custom cell class. Using tagged views is only good for very simple cells, and yours doesn't sound like a simple cell. Please create a custom subclass. Also, are you adding these views/gesture recognisers in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? Are you aware that table view cells are reused?

Comment: I was trying to add the view and gesture in the cellForRowAtIndexPath.  The pre-existing code had added their subviews the same way (although, the pre-existing subviews where much simpler).  Is this bad practice?  I noticed the code in cellForRowAtIndex path is reused when the user scrolls the tableview.  Is this what you mean?  Is this bad?

Answer (score 1):

It may be happening that the touch events of your table view would be cancelling the touch events of your UIView gesture, you may have to disable the table view selection of rows

Comment: This crossed my mind.  Do you have any suggestions on how I could verify if this is happening?

Comment: try setting, selectionStyleNone to your tableviewcell in cellForRowAtIndexPath and check if the guesture event is fired

Comment: I added     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; After the cell declaration inside cellForRowAtIndexPath.  It didn't seem to have any effects to table at all (good or bad).

Comment: I think this could be the problem.  I tried adding my UITapGestureRecognizer to the UITableView and the entire view registers the tap.  Now if only I can figure out how to get the tap down to the smaller play button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `userIntreactionEnable` for `UImageView` try this

```
-(UIView*) messagePlayerImageViewForMessage:(LAZMessage*) message {
UIView* returnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
UIImageView* playButtonImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[returnView addSubview:playButtonImageView];
playButtonImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
playButtonImageView.tag = TAG_CELL_PLAY_IMAGE_VIEW;

if ([self stringForMessageRecordingId:message]) {
    UIImage* playButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"play"];
    [playButtonImageView setImage:playButton];
    [playButtonImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, playButton.size.width/2, playButton.size.height/2)];

    [returnView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, playButtonImageView.frame.size.width, playButtonImageView.frame.size.height)];
}
returnView.tag = TAG_CELL_MESSAGE_PLAYER_VIEW;
return returnView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately still nothing.  I even tried adding that property to returnView for good measure - same.